# SQL Injection Prevention Python 3 Syntax - ".format" Replacement

Tags: python-3.x, sql-injection

I'm trying to use SQL in Python, and learned that using ".format" to perform SQL queries is not safe. BUT, I didn't find at all syntax that is appropriate for Python3 (from my understanding using "%" to represent the string is very old syntax - definitely not for Python 3). I'm looking for the correct (safe) syntax that I can use to perform simple queries (like getting information from the tables, but also to modify tables).

Comment: What type of database are you using? Is it has a PEP249 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) compliant interface, there should be a build in way.

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin. I'm not sure what is PEP249

Comment: Posting your Python code would probably be the easiest way to find out, but if thats not possible, what is the name of the module you use to execute SQL statements?

Comment: It's not possible to post the code, but I'm trying to understand how to use 'SELECT {} FROM {} {}' with correct safe syntax for Python 3. My intention is to prevent unwanted modification of the table (like drop table / delete etc.) , or unwanted insertions

Comment: It's not really possible to help you without you telling us what Python module you are using to execute SQL. For example the build-in module `SQLite` supports multiple different ways to format SQL code in  `execute` calls (https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) - most SQL modules contain similar functionality.

Comment: I'm using mysql.connect module:
sql =  'SELECT {} FROM {} {}'.format('*', table_name, '')
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
            table = self.cursor.fetchall()
I use these line to allow user to access to table according to provided table name. I need to avoid the possibility the user will be allowed to put bad queries (not in the way of intentional attack, more in the way of unaware users that mistakenly can do damage. Avoid the possibility to put some "drop table" or unintentional change to the DB). I'm trying to find the correct syntax to do so (for Python 3)